# Asp.Net Mvc Cloud hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cloud, web-hosting

Asp Net MVC project works fine in IIS Server ,But after uploading it to a cloud space ,it shows an error code 500.19 ,I put the database in cloud ,it also works fine with IIS

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script"> 
           <add name="PHP via FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe|-d open_basedir=C:" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
           <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
       </handlers>
       <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
                   arguments=".\TickLogicApplication.dll" 
                   stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                   stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
                   hostingModel="inprocess"/>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
        
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and in my local project .Can some one give me a solution?

Comment: You will have to edit the question and show us your `web.config` file as well as the exact 500.19 error page.

Comment: Now can you give me a solution @LexLi

Comment: Since all other tags are common, the most likely cause is that this cloud space does not support ASP.NET Core `<aspNetCore>` tag. Talk to their support guys and ask them to confirm whether they can help you enable ASP.NET Core, or you will have to switch to another hosting platform. BTW, you should also remove that "PHP via FastCGI" tag if you don't need PHP there.

Comment: but I can see some options in my website extension , Like Asp Net 4.0 (integrated pipeline)  etc.. @LexLi

Comment: It is well know that ASP.NET 4.x isn't ASP.NET Core. Talk to the support team please. Nobody here can help you on something they have no control of.

Comment: You may need to check full error message on the server since 500 is generic error. If you host it on shared server, your .net site won't be work automatically, you need to check your connection string. It seems that your connection string might be incorrect. If you are using shared hosting, you may refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-5-on-asphostportal-hosting/, the basic should be same.

Comment: Could you provide the detailed error information about 500.19?

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:
Module    IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code   0x8007000d
Config Error    
Config File  \\?\C:\HostingSpaces\ticklogicint.com\test.ticklogicint.com\wwwroot\va\web.config
Requested URL  http://test.ticklogicint.com:80/va
Physical Path   C:\HostingSpaces\ticklogicint.com\test.ticklogicint.com\wwwroot\va
Logon Method     Not yet determined
Logon User Not yet determined

Comment: @YurongDai  test.ticklogicint.com:80/va  this is my url

Comment: <aspNetCore processPath=".\TickLogicApplication.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />                                               while iam adding this line of code i am getting error to the cpanel .

Comment: This error is usually due to an invalid IIS configuration or an application access permission issue. Make sure to follow the ASP Core deployment instructions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 But your project runs fine on the IIS server, it just gets an error after uploading to the cloud space, so as Lex Li said, the cause of the problem is most likely that the cloud space does not support.

Comment: Thanks to all, for your response to my doubt.